# Material UI's TableRow not allowing a style override

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, material-ui

Im trying to override Material UI's default styles to make each TableRow have a margin between each other. However, it seems as if the override is not going through to the user interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`overrides` is a Theme setting, not a styling setting.

If you wish to set margins for ALL table rows to 30px (note. I would also suggest setting it to `theme.padding(3.75)` rather than explicitly defining it as 30px), then you should define it as an override in your Theme (see the [documentation on globals](https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/#css)).

If you only want to set the margins to 30px for a specific table then you can just use a regular CSS class.